# What is the name for half-baked understanding of philosophies?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, taoism, term, cognitive-psychology

I think many people who subscribe to Taoism pushing the idea to extremes, like thinking that only feeling is correct (in the name of the Tao cannot be spoken), or researching is useless (in the name of wu wei). As [RationalWiki](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Taoism#cite_ref-7) puts it: "separate out the ideas they find most palatable, and discard the rest as superstition"*. Even the Zhuangzi ridicules Confucius to the point that I feel disrespected and unacceptable. I also think that the reason the Tao cannot be spoken is because we have the [tip of the tongue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_of_the_tongue) phenomenon, which can be explained by modern cognitive psychology.

What I'm looking for is a name for half-baked understanding of a philosophy. It makes sense on the surface, but it pushes the ideas to the extremes that can be dangerous if you don't study it carefully. It's like [how Osho is perceived in Buddhism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/how-is-osho-seen-in-the-buddhist-community/2709#2709): "he's like the Tibetan saying, *honey on a razor blade*, if you are careful there's honey to be tasted, but if you are careless there's the razor blade." I guess the same critic can be apply to New Age.

I think this line of thinking is aligning with [naïve cynicism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_cynicism) (everyone is bias except me) and [naïve realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_realism_(psychology)) (who doesn't agree with me are irrational, or misinformed) in social psychology and philosophy of mind, and therefore there is a name for it. Do you know what it is?

<sup>*The context in there is about the distinction between philosophical Taoism and religious Taoism, so in a sense I take it out of context.</sup>

Comment: Not fully sure I understand the question, but "esoteric daoism" and "mystical daoism" come to mind ... (btw, you can spell it either Taoism or Daoism without difficulty in contemporary English).

Comment: perhaps I should read more on phil of mind, but what I'm looking for is like half-baked philosophies. It makes sense on the surface, but it pushes the ideas to the extremes that can be dangerous if you don't study it carefully. It's like [how Osho is perceive in Buddhism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/how-is-osho-seen-in-the-buddhist-community/2709#2709): "he's like the Tibetan saying, *honey on a razor blade*, if you are careful there's honey to be tasted, but if you are careless there's the razor blade." I guess the same critic can be apply to New Age.

Comment: I feel you would need to study Taoism more closely. What you say about it indicates a serious misunderstanding. In particular you would need to examine the reason why the Tao that is eternal cannot be spoken. This is not some odd Taoist idea but the explanation for the via negativa. If you understand this single point then you understand a lot. As for daft theories, I just call them daft.

Comment: @Gordon I'm sorry, it's not my intended question. If you look at the past edits you will see the original question is quite different, and the leftover of the first edit makes misunderstanding. The more I read the question the more I think there is no term for it. I also add a bit about the Zhuangzi. Also, no, the I-Ching is not a part of Taoism, if I understand it correctly

Comment: @PeterJ [negativa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negativa)? Also, can you check my clarification on the misunderstanding in the previous comment? Thanks.

Comment: @Ooker - Your comments on both Taoism and naive realism suggest that you've not quite sorted out what they are. Regarding Tao, the reason why it cannot be spoken is profound and to do with Unity and non-duality. Tao lies beyond the categories of thought and this is the idea you would need to grok. It is certainly nothing to do with the 'tip of the tongue' phenomenon. I'd recommend a book by Pamela Ball 'The Essence of Tao'. No offense intended but I'd say your question is an example of a 'half-baked' understanding for even naive realism is not what you describe.

Comment: I don't know the name but you found the place!

Comment: Half-baked understandings often have a name specific to the thing that's half-understood. Science has pseudoscience, buddhism has buddhist modernism and new age.. I don't know if there is a general way to describe a half-baked philosophy except as pseudo-something (if its based on something), or common names like confused or daft, as a commentor said above.

Answer (score 1):

I think that one problem you are observing is the conflict between Eastern thinking and Western thinking.

The way I see it, Western thinking was established in Ancient Greece with the writings of Aristotle and Plato, which were carried into the governing principles of the Roman Empire.  Western thinking was recrystallized many years later by Descartes, who held logic and causality above all else, declaring that while he can't be sure of the existence of anything else, "I see that myself is actually thinking, therefore I can be sure that at least I exist."

In Western thinking, *argument ad absurdum* is a common method for identifying problems with ideas.  Any idea that's applicable here, if true, is applicable there; and if it doesn't make sense there, then it can't be true here, either.

But in Eastern thinking (the way I see it), you have *acceptance of diverse ideas* characterized by polytheism and pantheism; and you also have *quieting of thought* characterized by the *koans* of Buddhism.  Both of these postures deny *argument ad absurdum*, yet have been embraced by many smart and good people throughout history.

It is natural that Eastern thoughts look funny from a Western perspective, just as Western thoughts look weird from an Eastern perspective.  Which one is true?  I cannot tell.

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding, but Eastern philosophy does not abandon the law of non-contradiction. There would be no true contradictions so no need to abandon it. Thus 'smart and good' people are able to embrace it. I may not be smart or good but no way would I endorse a philosophy that abandoned Aristotle's laws.

Answer (score 0):

Piaget talks about the distinction between:

- **accommodation**, where we restructure our internal models to better conform to new information, and...
- **assimilation**, where we restructure new information to better conform to our internal models.

What you're calling half-baked philosophy, I think, is generally a superficial form of assimilation: people trying to shove the round peg of a divergent worldview into the square hole of their own given understanding. I'm not suggesting that's bad, because both accommodation and assimilation are necessary aspects of learning. But it can be frustrating.

But really, I think this question confuses 'process' with 'product'. Philosophy is (metaphorically) the process of baking an idea. It takes time, effort, and conscientious skill to do it right, and most people are conspicuously negligent on all three. When we say that some idea is 'half-baked' we're not commenting on the *idea itself*; we're complaining that the (philosophical) chef went wrong somewhere in the process and produced something peculiar. And unfortunately, a lot of people are indiscriminate about what they feed their head with, perfectly content to chow down on even the most peculiar thing without really tasting it.

It doesn't really do any good to attack the thing itself, because people will continue to bake peculiar misunderstandings. Bring down one, and two will pop up in its place (like the myth of the Hydra). Instead, you need to show people how to bake (err... philosophically speaking).